# Spring binding Exception

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, bind

Im trying to get a project running on Spring MVC, this is my first approach, im trying to follow a tutorial from netbeans site but Im getting the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'empleado' available as request attribute
```

on my jsp:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        Name:
        <spring:bind path="empleado.num_empleado">
            <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
        </spring:bind>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object command,
        BindException errors) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
    Empleado emp = (Empleado) command;
    mv.addObject("nombre", empServ.consultarBD(emp.getNum_empleado()));
    return mv;
}
```

Im new to Spring MVC so maybe Im missing something obvious here. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like a problem with a bean called `empleado`. Probably this should be configured in your spring xml configuration file.

Comment: As far as I understand, empleado is the command name declared within the controller, Ive seen that exception when the name and the biding are not the same, but I double checked that.

Comment: The base path **MUST** exist on the request. You **MUST** add `empleado` object to your model / request attributes (e.g. in a same way you are adding `nombre` object).